# Mongoid hash property in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, factory-bot

How does one write a Factory Girl definition for a Mongoid class where one of the properties is a hash? (it is not an embedded document)

The Mongoid class looks something such as

```
class Foo
  field :bar, :type => Hash
end
```

so an instance of `Foo` should be able to access bar via `foo.bar['foobar'] = 1`

This cannot be depicted in a Factory Girl definition though by doing something like:

```
Factory.define :foo do |f|
  f.bar   {:foobar => 1}
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know FactoryGirl, but I'd guess that Ruby is interpreting the curly brackets as a block. This should work:

```
Factory.define :foo do |f|
  f.bar({:foobar => 1})
end
```